# Using printf("%s",&Buffer[i]); in C

Tags: c, printf, buffer

```
void Store(int temp){
    Buffer[i]=temp;
    i--;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Buffer[64]=00;

    int value = atoi(argv[1]);
    int base = atoi(argv[2]);

    char Table[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' , '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    //Mathmatical algorithm 
    while(value !=0){   
        digit = value%base;
        value = value/base;
        Store(digit);
        printf("%s",&Buffer[i]);
    }
```

I'm starting to learn C on my own. I'm trying to figure out how to use printf with this char Buffer[65]. Essentially, my algorithm pulls in a value and base given by the user, then calculates what that number is in that base. If I change my printf to print out digit, it prints "123" for 57 base 4. So, I have it storing digit into the Buffer array in reverse (set int i to 63 because i set 64 to null).

Long story short, when it stores into the buffer, increments down, then returns to the while loop it doesn't print any text.

Edit: As I'm looking around, it looks like printf only prints ascii characters. So I need to convert digit to one of the characters in Table[16]?

Comment: You're not initiating i

Comment: You store the value in `Buffer[i]` and then print `&Buffer[i-1]` which contains a nul character, representing end of string. Try moving the `printf` outside the `while` loop and printing `&Buffer[i+1]` - is that better?

Comment: @Lundin, gets warning without the &. warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
                        printf("%s",Buffer[i]);
                                ~~  ^~~~~~~~~
                                %c

Comment: @Kenney, no luck with moving outside while. If i just do printf(digit), it prints out 123. I need to reverse that to 321. So, I thought storing into the buffer at the end of the array (with buffer[64] being null), spaces 63 (i=63), 62 and 61 by incrementing downward would solve the issue

Comment: @Emi1305, I am initializing i as 63 outside of what i posted

Comment: @user3038573  You sure `Table` is not used as string anywhere in code ?

Comment: @ameyCU It's not, I was trying to run through maybe a set of if statements or a while loop and have it be "If digit == '1', then buffer[i]=table[1]".

Would that work?

Comment: @user3038573  No if it were used as string it will be **UB** .Just cleared it . But I am not familiar with `Buffer` . What is its type ?

Comment: @ameyCU Buffer is a char array, but is being printing as a string. I'm thinking i need to somehow convert Buffer[i] to the corresponding char in char Table

Comment: @user3038573 You have to post the declaration of Buffer. Unless your code is completely bogus, the printf line is one of the bugs. Maybe it is just a plain string, in which case you should `printf("%s", buffer);`, in which case you should read chapter 1 of any beginner level C programming book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working answer, though it only works up to base 16:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char Buffer[65];
int i = 63;

void Store(int temp){
    Buffer[i]=temp;
    i--;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Buffer[64]=00;

    int value = atoi(argv[1]);
    int base = atoi(argv[2]);

    printf( "%d in base %d = ", value, base );

    char Table[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' , '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    //Mathmatical algorithm
    while(value !=0){
        int digit = value%base;
        value = value/base;
        Store( Table[digit]);  // or: Buffer[i--] = Table[digit];
    }
    printf("%s\n", &Buffer[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kenney. This helps a ton. Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me figure it out. I'll look more into the whole &Buffer[i+1] deal. I just started C a few days ago and trying to get the grasp of how it all works.